# Xcode iOS UITableView Insert New Cell Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

Thanks in advance. I'm dealing with a single UITableView which is divided into different sections. Users can add or delete cells only from specific sections. The information displayed in the UITableView is stored in an array where each object represents a section:

> eg: tableItemsArray = ((arrayForSection1), (arrayForSection2), (arrayForSection3))

I have the animation set up to handle the delete as follows:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

I then programmatically remove the item from the array to remove it from the data model. However I am having difficulty in how to insert the cell in an animated form.

Currently I am running the current pseudo-algorithm:

1. Check item isn't anywhere in the array
2. Add item to array into a specific section
3. sort this section of the array alphabetically
4. reload the data

**Update**

When a new item is added to the array it is stored in a string to keep record of the new item. Once the array has been resorted I iterate through the array of cells to find its indexPath, then I delete the string (to prevent recursive insertion animations) and perform the animation, however the code doesn't animate its insertion into the table. I wondered whether that maybe the animation code (as below) wasn't working as I was using [tableView reloadData]?

```
// For Each Section in the table:
        for (NSMutableArray *object in sectionsInTable) {

            // For Each Cell in a section (Cells are stored in an array in index 1)
            for (NSString *label in [object objectAtIndex:1]) {
                if ([label isEqualToString:_insertedObject]) {
                    // New item
                    _insertedObject = Nil;
                    // animate addition
                    [self.labelListTableView beginUpdates];
                    [self.labelListTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[object objectAtIndex:1] indexOfObject:label] inSection:[sectionsInTable indexOfObject:object]]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
                    [self.labelListTableView endUpdates];
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas why the animation isn't working?

Thanks

D

Comment: I am a bit confused with "the sort algorithm doesn't end up providing me with an indexPath of the items new location."  If the issue is you don't know how to figure out the index you would want to change your question. Also if that is the case you might be looking for [myArray indexOfObject:newItem]; then create an index path based on the section and index of the object. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've extended my info above :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the [tableView reloadData] was preventing the animation.

```
// Annimate the new Item
        // For Each Section in the table:
        for (NSMutableArray *object in sectionsInTable) {
            // For Each Cell in a section:
            for (NSString *cell in [object objectAtIndex:1]) {
                if ([cell isEqualToString:_insertedObject]) {
                    // New item
                    _insertedObject = Nil;
                    // animate addition
                    [tableView beginUpdates];
                    NSInteger section = [sectionsInTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:object];
                    NSInteger row = [[object objectAtIndex:1] indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:cell];

                    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom ];
                    [tableView endUpdates];
                }
            }
        }
```